# Azure function failed to deploy with the error ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-deployment, azure-functions-core-tools

### Issue Description

I am trying to deploy the azure function using visual studio and getting the error: Web deployment task failed (Complete error logs are given below).
I have followed all the steps mentioned in the article http://techgenix.com/video-publish-azure-functions-azure-using-visual-studio-tools-azure-functions/ but still facing the issue.
Please help me as I have spent a lot of time on this issue and didn't get any solution.

Fiddler was not running when I deployed the azure function using visual studio.

#### Error logs

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestFunction, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>TestFunction -> C:\Repo\TestFunction\TestFunction\bin\Release\net461\bin\TestFunction.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
  Publish Started
  TestFunction -> C:\Repo\TestFunction\TestFunction\bin\Release\net461\bin\TestFunction.dll
  TestFunction -> C:\Repo\TestFunction\TestFunction\obj\Release\net461\PubTmp\Out\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-preview1-008174\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5): error : Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.) [C:\Repo\TestFunction\TestFunction\TestFunction.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-preview1-008174\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5): error :  [C:\Repo\TestFunction\TestFunction\TestFunction.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-preview1-008174\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5): error : Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED. [C:\Repo\TestFunction\TestFunction\TestFunction.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-preview1-008174\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5): error : Root element is missing. [C:\Repo\TestFunction\TestFunction\TestFunction.csproj]
  Publish failed to deploy.
```

Comment: Have you tried to publish it later? It seems a network issue.

Comment: is your function app stopped ????

Comment: Yes @JerryLiu, I have tried deployment of the azure function function multiple times in last one week. It didn't seems me an network issue as I am able to deploy an azure logic app from visual studio  without any issue. Issue occur only when I tried to deploy the azure function.

Comment: @Thomas, azure function is working fine on the local system, when I deploy it, App service is deployed successfully but azure function is not deployed and got the above given error.

Comment: @JerryLiu, I am working on a windows 10 virtual machine using visual studio 2017 professional edition. Other then azure function I am able to deploy everything.

Comment: Have you checked whether your advanced tool(kudu) in portal  is working? The deployment is connected there to upload your file.

Comment: @NarendraJangir again is your function appication is started on azure ? I am not talking about local

Comment: @JerryLiu, I am able to access the azure function kudu using url https://{myfunctionname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/. Here {myfunctionname} is my azure function name and due to security reasons I cannot provide the bexact name.

Comment: @Thomas, yes its started on azure at url https://{myfunctionname}.azurewebsites.net/ and showing me your function app is up and running but function code is showing blank on the portal as it is not deployed.

Comment: Maybe you should try to recreate a new function project and try to redpeloy ?

Comment: @Thomas, I have tried it multiple times by creating different solutions with different function name.

Comment: @NarendraJangir, have you tried to delete the whole function app in portal and redeploy with a different function app name?

Comment: @JerryLiu, yes I have tried the same and still the same issue.

Comment: @NarendraJangir Have you tried to create new resource group and new storage and app service plan to redeploy your function?